# What counts as a "Reschedule attempt" on the US Visa Scheduling site?

Tags: indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, us-visa

Since the usvisascheduling.com site allows a limited number of appointment reschedules, does anybody know (via personal experience / online source) what counts as a reschedule?

A. Does a cancellation + reschedule of a confirmed appointment (OFC + CA) count as 1 reschedule?

B. If I keep reserving OFC dates (but not getting CA dates), and then cancel the OFC slot to get an earlier date, does that also count as a reschedule? Or could I (hypothetically) keep doing this process till I get a close enough date?

For additional context, I am in India applying for a B1/B2 visa.